# Using dealloc method to release

Tags: objective-c, object, memory-management, uiviewcontroller, dealloc

I'm trying to understand memory management to do some better apps, but was stopped at one point :

I use some `UIButtons`. So I alloc them, work with them etc. But i need to release them at one moment.
So I implement `dealloc`method for all the object which are usefull all the time the `UIViewController` is on screen, and which need to be released when it desappeard. So in my `UIViewController` I implement :

```
-(void)dealloc
{
    NSLog(@"Dealloc call");
    [myButton release];
    .... //Some objects release
    [super dealloc];
}
```

But i never see the Dealloc call printed, so I think that it doesn't passed by the `dealloc` method when the `UIViewController` desappeard.

So, how does it work ? / What is false ?

Thanks !

EDIT : method to change of viewController :

```
-(void)myMethod
{
    if (!nextviewcontroller)
    {
        nextviewcontroller = [[NextViewController alloc]init];
    }
    UIView *nextView = nextviewcontroller.view;
    UIView *actualView = actualviewcontroller.view;
    [actualviewcontroller viewWillAppear:NO];
    [nextviewcontroller viewWillDisappear:NO];
    [actualView removeFromSuperview];
    [self.view addSubview:nextView];
    [actualviewcontroller viewDidAppear:NO];
    [nextviewcontroller viewDidDisappear:NO];
}
```

Comment: Some other object must still have a reference to your view controller do the view controller isn't being deallocated. You need to find out what still has the reference. Use Instruments to find the problem.

Comment: So you call your deallocation of viewcontroller when you change of view, right ?

Comment: You never call `dealloc` of any object directly.  The only time you ever call `dealloc` is when you do `[super dealloc]` at the end of your implementation of `dealloc` in your own class.  If you use ARC (**which you should**) you don't even do that.

Comment: No. You never call `dealloc`. Depending on how the view controller is presented, when it is dismissed, it should be deallocated but only if you don't have some other reference (on purpose or through a bug).

Comment: But when it's dismissed, it looks like not being deallocated. I add the method in the first post.

Comment: Retain cycles are a possible cause. A common error is having a view controller with a strong reference to its delegate, and the delegate a strong reference to its view controller. They live forever and never get deallocated.

Comment: I add the method to change of view controller